# How to determine / track / view the current internet connection speed? (in anytime and NOT BY TESTING USING APP)

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I know this sounds almost hopeless but I really need this.

I don't want to "test my internet speed" using Speed Test app because that is not true for every sites / every domain.

I want to view my internet speed in anytime tat is keep updating like what Android MIUI OS done, showing on top of screen (next to battery status).

**OR**

like PC under **Task Manager > Performance** tab, choose **Wi-Fi** and you can see the **Send** and **Receive** speed.

I hope I can do this as well for windows phone 10 **ANYWAY**, it can be via PC or anything as long as I can see what is the speed.

Why I need this?

OneDrive apps Up/Downloading is so SLOW-RESPONDING. I want to know is it really UPLOADING or NOT, sometimes it just stuck there.

***UPDATE:**

Not necessary OneDrive. If it's work, then it'll be useful for every download or upload when they are very slow. So I can check that is it up/downloading or not.

Comment: So do you want to know the current throughput, or the maximum theoretical throughput for the given current connection?

Comment: Based on the comment about Task Manager, I'm guessing they want to see current actual throughput, not theoretical.

Answer (score 3):

There's a way to do this using the built-in Device Portal feature. It's a bit long-winded, but for occasional troubleshooting that shouldn't be an issue. Follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings → Update & security → For developers
2. Enable "Developer mode" by selecting the corresponding option and confirming
3. Enable "Device Portal" and "Device discovery", and for added safety also enable authentication for Device Portal
4. Tap the "Pair" button, which will show you an access code
5. On your phone (or PC, or any other device on the same network), navigate to the IP address shown, enter the code from the previous step and click/tap "Submit"
6. Once logged in, select "Performance" from the left-hand side and scroll to the very bottom to see a real-time graph of network throughput
7. While there, also check out what else Device Portal gives you access to :)
8. Once done, don't forget to go through the steps in reverse and turn off everything you just enabled

[More about Windows Device Portal for Mobile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile)

Comment: A nice solution actually. However it is only run for about 10 seconds and disconnected (for my case), and I have to refresh over, maybe it is my network problem. Thanks anyway for the answer. (Answer upvoted) ;)

Comment: Interesting, it works fine for me for longer periods of time. Are you connected over WiFi? From the phone itself or another device? What phone do you have anyway?

Comment: I'm using Lumia 640 XL LTE. Connected to home WiFi (from Malaysia). :P