# Mysterious "SFT_5055W" app downloaded automatically by the Store

Tags: apps, store, security, app-update

An application, which I have never seen before, named "SFT_5055W" was updated automatically by the Store. Clicking on it brings me to the "Try that again" page with error code 1 and CV: M2S0/wO/eEKHxBy7, and I'm not clear on what this means.

Google searching this app returns pretty much nothing. The [Store page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/sft-5055w/9nblggh6ggrt) says that the product was removed.

I would be interested in knowing what this application is for, but my main question is: How do you prevent the Store from automatically installing and updating applications that you do not want?

[image: Store screenshot]

Comment: It seems that the app was made by Huizhou TCL for "system function testing" my phone, which has "5055W" in its model name somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The model number "5055W" refers to the [Alcatel Fierce XL](http://www.gsmarena.com/alcatel_fierce_xl_(windows)-7856.php). The app in question is made by Huizhou TCL Mobile Communication Co.Ltd. (see [cached version of the Store listing](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=sft_5055w&d=5006065120447733&mkt=en-WW&setlang=en-GB&w=_uSwM3c5i87kfscOTwXjI7QOPWlJmz0O)). I'm pretty sure this refers to [TCL Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCL_Corporation), which is based in the Chinese town of Huizhou and owns the Alcatel brand. Therefore, the mysterious app is nothing more than an OEM debug utility.

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to prevent the Store from auto-updating specific apps. You can, however, turn auto updates off for all apps in Store settings.

If you don't think you need the app, you can also uninstall it from the all apps list. Or if it doesn't show up there, try using the built-in Device Portal feature. See [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/14149/1401) for instructions on how to enable it. If that doesn't work either, then you're simply stuck with the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty much sure about the app but I can tell you how to get rid of automatic updation. Tap the triple bars present at the left top of the screen, now go to settings and toggle off the automatic updation. Next time no app will be updated but it will show in downloads and updates and will remain there forever until you manually allow it to install  by tapping download icon or tapping on update all button. I refer to "update on Wi-Fi option because store never installs any app automatically on cellular connection unless you have tried to install it on cellular connection previously and data connection gone in the midway downloading.