# Cannot find Gadgets App

Tags: windows-10-mobile, settings, lumia-640-xl, accessories

I have a Microsoft Lumia 640XL running Windows 10 Mobile, and last week, I reset it to start everything again. So, I noticed the gadgets app pops up whenever I connect a new peripheral to my phone, say, a bluetooth headset or wired headphones.

However, I cannot find the app in the apps list nor under Settings:

[image]
[image]

I can confirm the app is really installed, because on my start screen I pinned a tile of one of my accessories and I can open it via searching for it on the web & then launching it from the store, which is a very unreliable option.

Logic dictates that I could just uninstall and reinstall the app and it should be fixed, but I don't have a way of uninstalling it especially if its not showing in the apps list.

*PS: I already tried a soft reset, it did not work. A hard reset is not an option I would consider as I did that last week.*

**Question: How do I access or restore the app so that I can use it normally.**

Comment: What version of Windows 10 Mobile are you running exactly? Does the app show up in Settings -> Apps -> Apps & features? If so, try uninstalling or resetting it from there. You can also check out the built-in [Device Portal](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/14149/1401), it should also provide a way to uninstall apps. If those don't work, your only option might be to reset the phone again.

Comment: I'm running version 17.03, build 10.0.15063.483

Comment: FWIW, I have the exact same OS version on my Lumia 950, and Gadgets does show up in the all apps list. Did you try the other things I suggested?

Comment: Tried uninstalling it from under apps in settings, and then redownloading it. It worked. Thank you

Comment: Good to know! I've posted my comment as an answer, if you want to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gadgets should show up in the all apps list, not in Settings. If it doesn't, there's a few other places where you might be able to find and uninstall it:

1. Settings → Apps → Apps & features
2. Device Portal (see [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/14149/1401) for instructions on how to use it)